# run Shell command/ batch file with multiple lines from VBA

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file, cmd

I have 2 lines which i have to run in cmd everyday multiple times.  The lines resemble those below:

```
set_someclasspaths.bat
java -Xmx1024m foo.bar.stuff.Dashboard -var varone -from 20160701 -to 20160731 -outputdir c:\stuff -ir @ -dashboard
```

I have thought of two ways to automate this.  The first is a batch file and the second is send keys.  I have made a file labeled it something.bat and pasted in the above two lines.  This quickly opens a window in cmd and closes again (even if i add pause at the end), and doesnt do what i'd expect- infact as far as i can tell it runs the first command then nothing.

The send keys method only seems to run the first line, I have tried:

```
Sub testcreate()
Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

wsh.Run "cmd.exe /K C:\a\b\set_someclasspaths.bat", windowStyle, waitOnReturn
wsh.sendkeys "java -Xmx1024m foo.bar.stuff.Dashboard -var varone -from 20160701 -to 20160731 -outputdir c:\stuff -ir @ -dashboard"
End Sub
```

My batch file and java ability are dubious at best, it would seem like the neater way to solve this is the batch file, so i would prefer to do that.

I guess i am passing parameters to a java script in the second line, im not sure if there is syntax for this, and without learning some java and batch file stuff I've ground to a halt.

To clarify, my question is two fold: first is the batch file the better way to do this?  Second, why is this not working?

Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call one batch file from another, control is passed to the second and it doesn't return.

If you'd like it to return, you need to pass in `call`, so your batch file will look like this:

```
call set_someclasspaths.bat
java -Xmx1024m foo.bar.stuff.Dashboard -var varone -from 20160701 -to 20160731 -outputdir c:\stuff -ir @ -dashboard
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
Sub CreateAndRun()

Dim batchContents As String
Dim batchFile     As String
Dim FF            As Byte

batchFile = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\temp.bat"

batchContents = "CALL set_someclasspaths.bat" & vbCrLf & _
                "java -Xmx1024m foo.bar.stuff.Dashboard -var varone -from 20160701 -to 20160731 -outputdir c:\stuff -ir @ -dashboard"

FF = FreeFile

Open batchFile For Output As #FF
    Print #FF, batchContents
Close #FF

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run batchFile, 1, True

DoEvents

Kill batchFile

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a wrapper batch file like wrapper.bat and paste your two commands in there:

```
call set_someclasspaths.bat
java -Xmx1024m foo.bar.stuff.Dashboard -var varone -from 20160701 -to 20160731 -outputdir c:\stuff -ir @ -dashboard
pause
```

This should execute both the batch file and your java statement and then keep the window open.

Instead of having to create a batch file via VBA all the time, you can just simply execute it when you click on a button or something.